# How to refresh sitecore tree node after edit that item and publish it

Tags: c#, asp.net, tree, sitecore

I need to refresh sitecore tree node after publish it.
Current behaviour is when I update some item and publish, sitecore tree node does not get refreshed.
I have to manually refresh the sitecore tree node.
How to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently created a command where

```
Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, "item:load(id=" + item.ID + ")");
```

is used to load the newly created node. Maybe that works for you as well.

Comment: So, where can I find the publish popup window, publish button event? I have to put this code to that publish button click event, right?

Comment: I've been looking at the publish button - /sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Publish/Publish - it executes the command "item:publishnow"

But I think it might be easier to attach to one of the publish events. I did this in my projects for creating a pdf every time the item was published.

Answer (score 1):

John West has the best approach of this problem:

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/load-or-reload-an-item-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms