# How to attach new event to sitecore publish button

Tags: c#, asp.net, tree, sitecore

I need to refresh my sitecore tree nodes after I publish my items.
In core database, when we goto sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Publish/Publish item, there is a field called "Click". item:publishnow already there. My question is how do I add additional my own event to here.

[image]

Comment: Your question was asked and answered a couple of days a go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759624/how-to-refresh-sitecore-tree-node-after-edit-that-item-and-publish-it/15765930#15765930

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this question was already answered as TwentyGotoTen mentions, a little more information:
If you open your Commands.config (located in the App_Config folder) you'll see `<command name="item:publishnow" type="Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.PublishNow,Sitecore.Kernel" />` or something similar located in there somewhere. You could either create your own publish event and replace the `item:publishnow` command or you could use an event which you can define in the `<events>` node in the web.config. There should be an event called `publish:end` in there. If you create your own event you can call that after the `publish end` and have it reload your item.

As mentioned in the other question, John West has a great article about [loading or reloading an item in Sitecore](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/08/Load-or-Reload-an-Item-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx). 
Also, another one of John Wests articles is [All about events in Sitecore](http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-Events-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx), which would be a good read if you want to create your own event.

Comment: This is the thing that I needed. Thank you very much. Even I went through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759624/how-to-refresh-sitecore-tree-node-after-edit-that-item-and-publish-it/15765930#15765930 , but I couldn't figure out my answer.